# Magento:2 To add custom block in layout

Tags: magento2, layout, custom, customer-account

I wanted to add a custom block in my account page after account information.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Account</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new_info" as="new" template="Magento_Customer::custominfo.phtml"/>
        <move element="new_info" destination="content" after="customer_account_dashboard_info"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want `custominfo.phtml` file should run after account information section.

Answer (score 2):

You try this layout

**customer_account_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>         
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new_info" as="new" after="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="Magento_Customer::custominfo.phtml"/>            
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```